# Sprite Kit/Swift Stars Effect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, effect

this is what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Stars spawning randomly, resizing an image of a little dot so it seems like the "stars are glowing" in random positions. 
I just started working with Swift few weeks ago, and I'm working on this cool game project, this could be a great feature, and I'm sure some of the other users could use and answer to this too.

Any ideas?

edit: And sorry for being such a newbie.

Comment: Check out SKEmitterNode that is built into sprite kit.

Comment: Still, I don't really know how to use documentation.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `CAEmitterLayer`, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/index.html). It's quite straight forward.

In case you have doubts, I have combined SpriteKit, even OpenGL with standard Core Animation without any issues.

Comment: That looks great. Could you please provide any code sample? I don't really know how to get my head around it.

Comment: I could not "get my head around it" either in 63 seconds, lol. You are expected to do a minimum of your own research. - That being said, check out [Dazzle](https://github.com/lichtschlag/Dazzle), and accept this answer.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, problem is not with CAEmitterLayer, it's I don't really know how to use documentation to use it in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about Sprite-kit now you can use `SKEmitterNode`.

Make a new Xcode file:

[image]

```
let stars : SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("stars", ofType: "sks")!) as! SKEmitterNode
stars.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
stars.zPosition = 1
self.addChild(stars)
```